# Asyncio: appending return values to a list

Tags: python-asyncio

I am trying to implement asyncio in a previously working program but my functions are returning coroutines instead of the objects I expect.

Example:

```
async def requester(things):

    async def adder(item):
        output = {}
        output['timestamp'] = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
        output['key'] = item
        return output

    to_insert = []
    for thing in things:
        to_insert.append(adder(thing))

    mongodbcollection.insert_many(to_insert) # This throws the error

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(requester(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

In this example, instead of objects being returned from the adder function, coroutines are returned, and naturally when I try to insert them into a database it throws `TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping`. There are other asynchronous things happening in each of these functions, that is why they are async. How can I get this internal function to return the object as intended?

Comment: If `addr` isn't asynchronous, don't use `async def` (but be careful about introducing blocking code). If it is, you need to use `await`.

Comment: It is and I am, I just didn't include it because these are huge functions with a lot going on. It awaits on some aiohttp requests.

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant now. I was awaiting things inside the async function but I wasn't awaiting the result of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [should use](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#async-def) `await` to execute a coroutine and get a result of the execution:

```
to_insert = []
for thing in things:
    res = await adder(thing)
    to_insert.append(res)
```

---

There's also a chance `insert_many` should also be awaited if it's a coroutine.